# Procedure for alpha blending textured quads in OpenGL 3+?

Tags: opengl

I am attempting to put together a simple program that just displays two textured quads overlapping each other, and the textures have alpha channels.

I have successfully been able to get the quads themselves to display, and the textures look correct except for the transparency.

On this topic, the GL_BLEND flag does not seem to do anything at all, whether it is enabled or not. Is this particular flag inapplicable when shaders are being used?

I know for a fact that the alpha is being rendered in correctly, since if I set out_color = texture.aaaa, I get a nice pattern of blacks/whites/grays that match the original texture.

So, if GL_BLEND doesn't work, what are the usual methods for getting alpha blending working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` does is turn blending on and off. It does not say what the blending will do; that is controlled by the [various blending functions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending). If you want a typical alpha transparency blend, you do this:

```
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

If you use pre-multiplied alpha (and you probably should), you would do:

```
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
```

Comment: I was originally using `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` to set it (based on me reading the documentation), but I tried these too, but I'm still getting the same issue. It seems to be "sort of" transparent, in that the quads get the background color (black) in the transparent parts, but don't show the quads underneath each other. So basically, the extra space on the quad is filled with an opaque black, somehow.

Comment: @Kozaki: That's a matter of transparency, which requires [rendering the objects in the proper order.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)

Comment: Ah, this is me facepalming. I could've sworn I had everything sorted, but I didn't. Everything finally works! Thank you very much!